# What do these characters mean?(ANSI Code)

Tags: ansi-escape

It's the code I'm printing with node:

```
const m = `[38;5;1;48;5;16m TEST`
console.log(m)
```

output:
[image]

It changes the text color.
As you can see `` is a special char I don't understand(It's not being shown by the browser). How does it work?

[image]

Is there any alternative for `ESC`?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code. What do you mean by "alternative"?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing The `ESC` char is only shown in the IDE. Why? I can't find this char in the documentation as well.

Comment: That character is called "escape", it's at ASCII position 27. That's why they are called escape sequences. And no, normally it's not a printable character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @puucee already mentions they are terminal control characters. I find it surprising that it says `ESC[` in the code as that won't be escaped in normal node. I suspect that maybe your IDE is converting the "true" escape character to `ESC`. Node does not support octal escapes (such as `\033`), but hexadecimal escapes. That is, you string should usually be like this:

`console.log('\x1b[38;5;1;48;5;16m TEST \x1b[0m')`

Comment: I changed it to `\x1b` and it still works the same. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

These are terminal control characters. They are often used e.g. for coloring the output. Some are non-printable. Backticks ` in your javascript example are called template literals.

Comment: Do you know what `ESC` char is? I didn't find it in the documentations.

Comment: It marks the start of escape sequence "\033[". It's octal 33 in ascii table.

Comment: It's not octal. When I replace it with `\033` I get this error: `SyntaxError: Octal escape sequences are not allowed in template strings`. I still don't understand what that char is but changing it to `\x1b` gives the same result.